# move a downloaded file from python backend(Rest API) to /storage/emulated/0/Download in flutter

Tags: python-3.x, flutter, flask

**Basically I'll provide a input field in the mobile app where user's will paste the YouTube Url & sends the url to the backend Rest API,the Rest API will download the video.The problem is video should get downloaded to this location /storage/emulated/0/Download of the mobile storage**

**Error, the videos is getting downloaded in the backend.I.e on my local machine instead of mobile storage location**

Rest API code for downloading the video

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pytube import YouTube
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/Youtube', methods=["POST"])
def youtube():
    youtube_link_request = request.get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)
    print(youtube_link_request)
    youtube_link = youtube_link_request['link']
    downloads = youtube_link_request['path']
    print(downloads);
    yt = YouTube(youtube_link).streams.first().download()
   ## YouTube(youtube_link).streams.first().download() will starting downloading the video
    views = YouTube(youtube_link).views
    thumbnail = YouTube(youtube_link).thumbnail_url
    title = YouTube(youtube_link).title
    # streams_data = yt.streams.first().download()
    # streams = []
    # for stream in streams_data:
    #     stream_info = stream
    #     streams.append(stream_info.type)
    return jsonify({"Data": "successful completed",
                    "views": views,
                    "thumbnail": thumbnail,
                    "title": title,

                    }), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Apart of flutter code

```
 RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final PermissionHandler _permissionHandler =
                      PermissionHandler();
                  var result = await _permissionHandler
                      .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);

                  // var dir = await
                  if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                    if (result[PermissionGroup.storage] ==
                        PermissionStatus.granted) {
                      var dirpath =
                          await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                              ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

                      final UrlModel = await passInfo(urlTextController.text);
                      // _loading ? LinearProgressIndicator() : _urlModel;

                      setState(() {
                        _loading = !_loading;
                        _urlModel = UrlModel;
                        views = _urlModel.views;
                        title = _urlModel.title;
                        thumbnail = _urlModel.thumbnail;
                      });
                      print(dirpath);
                    }
                    // print(title);
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "${_urlModel.title}",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1);
                  } else {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Error",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1);
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Error is the videos is getting downloaded in the backend.I.e on my local machine instead of mobile storage location

Comment: You can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66390687/6875197

Answer (score 1):

It looks logical to me, You need to run a webserver like `Nginx` and copy all downloaded files to your webserver root directory, then you have your server host address with the address of the file, so it will be like this `server_ip:server_port/name_of_the_file_downloaded.mkv`, provide it to the flutter app, so the user will download it to `/storage/emulated/0/Download`.